# How can I check with Python which Window Manager is running?

Tags: python, gnome, kde-plasma

I want to check which Window Manager the user is using (like GNOME or KDE etc.). How do I do that?

Comment: If you expand on "why" you want to detect it, someone might have a better idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the name of the X window manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758648/find-the-name-of-the-x-window-manager)

Comment: You might be able to check for specific processes which are usually running when user is using either of those windows managers. I haven't really checked this hence the comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no central place where a program registers itself to say "hi, I'm the window manager".

For instance, I'm running [xmonad](http://xmonad.org). I simply start this by calling `xmonad` in my `~/.xsession` file along with a couple of other programs to have it start when I login. You cannot really detect that.

Comment: I just thought of something, the Window Manager is just like any other program right? So it is in the processes list, for example, I'm running GNOME, and I got a process called 'gnome-sessions'. So I could check if that process is running so I know the user uses GNOME. You can't run 2 or more WM's at the same time anyhow right?

Comment: @Jay: Sure, if you have a list of all window managers, I suppose you could. There are a lot of different ones though. You cannot make a general solution.

Comment: See `xnest` or `Xephyr` or `startx -- :1` for reasons why your assumption of "can't run 2 or more WM's at the same time" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're apparently using linux, you could use [wmctrl -m](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) or [inxi -Sxx](https://smxi.org/docs/inxi-man.htm).

```
import subprocess

def get_wm():

    output = subprocess.run(['wmctrl', '-m'], text=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if output.stderr:
        return(output.stderr)
    else:
        return(output.stdout)

print(get_wm())
```