# How to detect if xlib application running from xinit?

Tags: c, command-line-interface, x11, xlib, kde-plasma

I write an *xlib* C application. I need different behavior of it, depending if it running with `xinit ./myapp` from CLI when no X server started, from running in normal KDE desktop.

*argv[0]* returns same value in both cases (i.e. not sees `xinit` prefix).

How i can determine when `xinit` was used for starting my app?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The xinit is going to start the X server, therefore in both cases you can assume that the X server is running. As far as I know there are no ways to determine such thing.

Comment: Are you just looking for whether a window manager is running?  If so, then maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758648/find-the-name-of-the-x-window-manager) will help.  There are still other ways to start X without a DE / window manager besides using `xinit`, so checking for `xinit` is perhaps not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. I do not know how to describe my task more precisely, not really i need about exactly `xinit` (or X server or so). Maybe yes i need to know is Window manager is running. In fact i just need to determine if `kwin`'s *color inversion* is active (and this is answer why i need to detect, even when i know that *A X program should not have to care under which window manager it is displayed.* in URL above). But it is quite complex to determine inversion exactly. But because inversion is turned on permanently in KDE for me, i can maybe test for Window manager is running...

Currently, using suggested solution, i was able to solve it at least for my particular case. But not sure if it portable enough.

```
fp = popen("/usr/bin/xprop -root _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run `/usr/bin/xprop -root _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK`\n" );
    exit(1);
}
fgets(cmdout, sizeof(cmdout), fp);
pclose(fp);
i = strncmp(cmdout, "_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK(WINDOW): window id #", 40);
if (i == 0) {
    inverted_colors = 1;
    printf ("Window manager detected.\n");
} else {
    inverted_colors = 0;
    printf ("No window manager detected.\n");
}
```